# Continue along a path of 'elseif' in PHP, even if past-condition is met?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to create a "add to string if condition" is met function, here's my actual code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( '_s_posted_on' ) ) :

    function _s_posted_on( $params = array() ) {

        $output = 's'; /** Holds the string of the code output by the arguments. */

        if ( in_array('time', $params) ) : /** Begin main loop */
            /**
            Show the time of the post
            */

            $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';

            $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
                esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
                esc_html( get_the_date() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
                esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
            );

            $posted_on = sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: post date. */
                esc_html_x( 'Posted on %s', 'post date', '_s' ),
                '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
            );

            $output .= '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span>';

        elseif ( in_array('author', $params) ) :
            /**
            Show the post's author
            */

            $author = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: post author. */
                esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', '_s' ),
                '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
            );

            $output .= '<span class="author"> ' . $author . '</span>';

        elseif ( in_array('category', $params) ) :
            /**
            Show the post's category.
            */

            $categories = (array) wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );

            $category_string = sprintf (
                esc_html_x( 'in %s', 'post_category', '_s' ),
                '<a class="category">' . $categories[0] -> name . '</a>'
            );

            $output .= '<span class="category">' . $category_string . '</span>';

        else :
            $output = 'No info about the post!';

        endif; /** End main loop */
        echo '<div class="post-meta-info"' . $output . '</div>';
    }
endif;
```

Calling `_s_posted_on('time', 'category');` only outputs the code from `time`, yet it should output the code from `time`and `category` since both conditions are met.

The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
if (string_exists_in_params($string, $params)):
    add_to_my_string --> $string2;
elseif (string_exists_in_params($string1, $params)):
    add_to_string --> $string1;
elseif (string_exists_in_params($string2, $params)):
    add_to_string --> $string2;
```

The problem is that the loop breaks every-time it hits a condition, so say I'd call my function `_s_posted_on` with `$string1, $string2`, my `output` should be the results of `$string1` and `$string2` but unfortunately, it stops at `$string1` and doesn't go further to check for `$string2`.

In short, I'm trying to add to a string, based on some conditions, where 2 conditions can be present, but the loop stops at the first condition met and breaks.

Comment: Have you tried multiple `ifs` without `else ifs`?

Comment: @Erwin Nope! Would that make sense, though? I'm looking for something that'd be a `also-if`, but multiple `ifs` just break the script. Edit: It works. Thank you.

Comment: Your method doesn't quite seem refined to me.  I'd like to better understand the potential data stored in `$params`.  I assume you have control of the elements and their order -- how is this array generated?  Using multiple full array scans cannot be the most efficient way.   Please offer the details that I am requesting so that I may extend some best practice advice.  Thank you.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for the interest! So, here's exactly the code used that generates the `$params` : `<?php _s_show_post_info(array('author','time')); ?>` As such, in my `_s_show_post_info`, I just look if the item is in the array with `in_array`.

Comment: That's not what I mean / what I am asking about.  How is `array('author','time')` generated?  Are you manually writing it? Is it generated automatically from code elsewhere? Please clarify because I need to isolate if `array('time','author')` is possible.

Comment: @mickmackusa I write it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try multiple `ifs` with flag for `else`

```
$flag = false;
if (string_exists_in_params($string, $params)):
    add_to_my_string --> $string2;
    $flag = true;

if (string_exists_in_params($string1, $params)):
    add_to_string --> $string1;
    $flag = true;

if (string_exists_in_params($string2, $params)):
    add_to_string --> $string2;
    $flag = true;

if ($flag == false):
    $output = 'No info about the post!';
```

Comment: Erwin, any reason for the flag?

Comment: In case first 3 conditions are not met, flag will remain false. Which will return the last condition true and returns `$output = 'No info about the post!';` which is equal to your `else` statement

Answer (score 1):

`elseif` means, if the previous condition did not pass, and this permission do pass, then do it. It sounds like you just want to have multiple `if` statements after one another, which is completely normal and fine to do.

So you can do

```
if($a == true) {
  // Execute this if $a is true.
}

if($b == true) {
  // Execute this if $b is true, no matter if the first if 
  // statement was executed or not.
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If it helped, please mark my answer as the correct answer. I'm happy that it helped you.

Comment: @JonathanGuerin You accept the answer by pressing on the empty check-mark next to the answer, below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Code:

```
if(!function_exists('_s_posted_on')){
    function _s_posted_on($params=array()){

        $params=array_intersect(array('time','author','category'),$params);  // filter and sort

        if(empty($params)){  // this provides a shortcut whereby NO additional conditions or function calls are required
            $output = 'No info about the post!';
        }else{
            $output=''; // I don't understand why your string should start with `s` so I am omitting it
            foreach($params as $param){  // iterate upto 3 times total
                if($param=='time'){  // function-less conditional check
                    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';

                    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
                        esc_attr(get_the_date('c')),
                        esc_html(get_the_date()),
                        esc_attr(get_the_modified_date('c')),
                        esc_html(get_the_modified_date())
                    );

                    $posted_on = sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: post date. */
                        esc_html_x('Posted on %s','post date','_s'),
                        '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" rel="bookmark">'.$time_string.'</a>'
                    );

                    $output.='<span class="posted-on">'.$posted_on.'</span>';
                }elseif($param=='author'){  // function-less conditional check
                    $author = sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: post author. */
                        esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', '_s' ),
                        '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="'.esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))).'">'.esc_html(get_the_author()).'</a></span>'
                    );

                    $output.='<span class="author"> '.$author.'</span>';
                }else{ // can only be `category` due to filtration step and prior conditions
                    $categories=(array) wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(),'category');

                    $category_string=sprintf(
                        esc_html_x('in %s','post_category','_s'),
                        '<a class="category">'.$categories[0]->name.'</a>'
                    );

                    $output.='<span class="category">'.$category_string.'</span>';
                }  // end `param` conditional
            }  // end foreach
        }  // end `empty` conditional

        echo '<div class="post-meta-info">'.$output.'</div>';  // (generally, return is used in functions instead of echoing)
        // I added this greater than sign^  <-- it seems rather important!
    }
}
```

Points / Explanations:

- Rather than colon-syntax condition blocks, I recommend curly brackets for improved readability.
- Because there is a finite number of eligible elements in `$params` AND because the order of the elements is important, I recommend using `array_intersect()` from the start.  By putting your "actionable" elements in order all other processes down-script are simplified.  (If you are generating these elements manually, you can omit this step -- assuming you are not adding "non-actionable" elements.) Here is a demo of what my filter/sort step does: [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd355034356af7282b5e1bb0ba9b875c22b12063)
- Always try to write early exiting conditions in your condition blocks (and loops for that matter).  If there are no actionable elements, then skip straight to the end -- don't check for `time` and then `author` and then `category` -- this is a matter of efficient / best practice.
- I don't know why your `$output` string starts with `s`, so I removed it.
- I was able to completely eliminate the `in_array()` calls. The `if-elseif-else` block inside of the `foreach()` now makes no function calls and, in fact, doesn't even need to check for `category` because it is guaranteed logically.
- I added the missing `>` to `<div class="post-meta-info"`.
- Generally, as a matter of best practice, functions are typically written to `return` something rather than `echo` something.  If you want to echo `$output` more professionals will recommend `echo _s_posted_on($params=array());`.  I don't have intimate knowledge of your project, so maybe you have a good reason to do it your way.

Comment: @JonathanGuerin I have posted a clean/refined function for you with a comprehensive explanation.  If you have questions please ask.  If you feel it is the best answer, you may move the green tick, but you are under no requirement to do so.

Comment: Amazing write-up. Definitely makes a lot more sense. I wonder though, how would this compare speed wise? And also, any additional resources that I can use to bolster up my PHP code?

Comment: The best practices in my answer ensures that this will run faster than other methods.  If you are manually writing the params in order and using an empty array when `time`,`author`, and `category` are not present, then you can eliminate the `array_intersect()` line.  The smartest thing is checking for an empty array first and providing the shortcut to the end of the function.  Using the foreach loop means you don't have to go to the expense of `in_array()` multiple times.  This is the answer that you and future readers should be using.  How exactly do you want to "bolster up" you code?

Comment: Understood. To be fair, "bolstering up" comes in time, as you get experience, but for Python, there are plenty of resources that tell you when it's faster to use dictionaries or lists. For JS, there's profilers and so on. What's my go to for PHP (1) speed optimization and (2) learning about logic flow?

Comment: In this case, no one is going to notice any differences in speed of execution.  The point I am making is completely about logic flow (speed micro-optimization is just a side-effect).

Comment: oh, and I forgot to mention that my method doesn't require a `flag` variable -- because I wrote the "empty" conditional check first.